# MongoDB Node.js 'ignoreUndefined' option does nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-nodejs-driver

In the Node.js MongoDB module passing `{ignoreUndefined: true}` as an option to the `MongoClient.connect` method seems to not do anything. I believe the expected behavior should be to prevent all `undefined` data fields from taking a `null` value when being written to the database (causing them to not be stored). Incidentally, passing `{ignoreUndefined: true}` to each individual write method does accomplish this.

So, why does passing `{ignoreUndefined: true}` to the `connect` method not "ignore undefined"? If this is not the expected behavior, then what is?

Comment: What documentation are you following & what code reproduces the problem?

Comment: I'm using this documentation: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/MongoClient.html

To reproduce: MongoClient.connect(DBURL, { ignoreUndefined: true },......

Comment: Running that partial statement won't reproduce the problem, right?

Comment: @D.SM To reproduce the problem, use the MongoClient.connect method with the option {ignoreUndefined: true}. Then use any write method (such as insertOne), to to insert this object {field: undefined}. The field will be equal to null in the db, in contrast to the expected behavior. Not sure where my question was unclear on this

Comment: I wonder if those options are even being read, because `{promoteLongs: false}` (default is true) also doesn't keep long values represented in the Long class, it still promotes them to numbers when it can.

Comment: Hello @TreverThompson, how do you accomplish the passing {ignoreUndefined: true} to each individual write method? In the docs that is not specified.. https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#insertOne